# Why doesn't tsqlt support not null columns?

Tags: tsqlt

After looking at the code it seems overly simple:

in [tSQLt].[Private_CreateFakeOfTable]
change

CASE WHEN cc.IsComputedColumn = 1 OR id.IsIdentityColumn = 1

to

CASE WHEN cc.IsComputedColumn = 1 OR id.IsIdentityColumn = 1  or c.is_nullable = 0

It's so simple, even to make it conditional upon an additional parameter, that it makes me wonder what the reasoning is behind it not being supported out of the box.  I'm currently tempted to change it before starting to use it but thought I'd find out why - in case the ramifications are important.

Comment: What is the error you are getting? Can you post example code?

Comment: Well, that's the problem.  There aren't any errors.  
We have several complex procedures that must collect intermediate results for performance reasons.  A test failure due to incorrect output is much harder to diagnose if the procedure doesn't throw like it typically would if a null landed somewhere that 'in real life' could never happen.

Comment: tSQLt is not a debugging tool. If your procedure is too complex to understand, maybe that is what you need to address?

Comment: My only question was whether there were ramifications.  Otherwise it doesn't make any sense to arbitrarily give up valuable information for no reason.  As I said, I've never used the tool.  If I implement it I want as much advantage to using it as possible.

Answer (score 1):

tSQLt does make all columns nullable in any faked table. That is kind of the purpose of faking the table in the first place.

However, it seems you are looking for a temporary solution to make a column not-nullable so you can catch an error. In that case, I'd manually alter the column in question to be `NOT NULL` after faking the table.

And to answer your second question, there is no intrinsic technical reason to not have a switch to preserve nullability. There just never was a need for it so far.

Comment: Thanks.  That's what I wanted to know.  
I don't think leaving it off makes any sense since all it does is throw away useful information for no good reason.  If I ever find a situation where it makes sense to be able to turn it off I'll add a toggle param but my initial implementation will have it ON by default.